# What problem excatly did Sommerfield solve in his atomic model and how?

Tags: atomic-physics, history, atoms, orbitals, models

I am curious to know what problem did [Sommerfield](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/SommerfeldModel.html) solve in his atomic model and how does his atomic model solve it? Most books say it solved the problem of splitting of lines but what excatly does it mean? what is splitting of lines problem? Please explain me. A simple explanation about Sommerfield's atomic model in your answer will be apperciated.

Comment: Why not just to read book  ATOMBAU UND SPEKTRALLINIEN von 
ARNOLD SOMMERFELD 
I BAND ?

Comment: I don't have time to read a book can you tell me the overview of that book  : )